# In a Java EE servlet container (JBoss) is it possible to include a classes directory inside an EAR?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, ear

I would want these classes on the classpath and have them implicitly available to all EJBs and WARs. Is this possible without having to create a "commons jar" and having to explicitly put it on the classpath for an EJB or WAR?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

If you want the classes to be embedded with your EAR then you can store them under the LIB directory under your EAR

```
app.ear
|--META-INF/application.xml
|--lib/
     |-library1.jar
     |-library2.jar
|
|--ejb-component1.jar
|--ejb-component2.jar
|--ui-war1.war
     |-WEB-INF/lib/library3.jar
|--ui-war2.war
     |-WEB-INF/lib/library4.jar
```

If you have multiple EAR files that share the same libraries then you can simply copy those libraries into JBoss/server/{config - default/all etc...}/lib

In either cases, the class files will be available to your application and you don't need to provide those jar explicitly in your classpath.

Comment: Is it required that they be in JARs, or will something like lib/classes/path/to/class/MyClass.class work?